# Rails 3 - save few models with foreign keys in same time

Tags: ruby, model, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have models **User**, **Teacher**, **TeacherEducation**. **TeacherEducation** belongs to **Teacher**, **Teacher** belongs to **User**.

I use nested attributes to save everything via one line in my controller `user.save`. But I met thing which I can't solve. I can set id for Teacher, but I can't give id for **TeacherEducation** before I can save **Teacher**.

Is it possible to fix that and keep using nested attributes in my models?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor   :password                                                               
  attr_accessible :user_login,                                                           
                  :password,
                  :teacher_attributes
  has_one :teacher
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teacher 
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :teacher_last_name,
                    :teacher_first_name,
                    :teacher_middle_name,
                    :teacher_birthday,
                    :teacher_sex,
                    :teacher_category,
                    :teacher_education_attributes
  belongs_to :user 
  has_one :teacher_education
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teacher_education

  validates :user_id,             
            :presence => true
end

class TeacherEducation < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :teacher_education_university,
                    :teacher_education_year,
                    :teacher_education_graduation,
                    :teacher_education_speciality
  belongs_to :teacher

  validates :teacher_id,             
            :presence => true

  ...
end
```

My controller

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
 def create_teacher  
    user = User.new( params[:user] )      
    user.user_role = "teacher"   
    user.teacher.user_id = current_user.id    # Work                                            
    user.teacher.teacher_education.teacher_id = user.teacher.id # Doesn't work

    if user.save
    ...
    end
 end
end
```

So, `user.teacher.teacher_education.teacher_id = user.teacher.id` doesn't work.

UPD

**Error**

```
Teacher teacher education teacher can't be blank, Teacher user can't be blank
```

View - **new_teacher.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => create_teacher_url, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
  <%= field_set_tag do %>
        <%= f.fields_for :teacher do |builder| %>
      <div class="control-group">
        <%= builder.label :teacher_last_name, "Фамилия", :class => "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= builder.text_field :teacher_last_name, :value => @teacher_last_name %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <%= builder.label :teacher_first_name, "Имя", :class => "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= builder.text_field :teacher_first_name, :value => @teacher_first_name %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <%= builder.label :teacher_middle_name, "Отчество", :class => "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= builder.text_field :teacher_middle_name, :value => @teacher_middle_name %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <%= builder.label :teacher_sex, "Пол", :class => "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= label_tag nil, nil, :class => "radio" do %>
            <%= builder.radio_button :teacher_sex, 'm', :checked => @user_sex_man %>
            Мужской
          <% end %>

          <%= label_tag nil, nil, :class => "radio" do %>
            <%= builder.radio_button :teacher_sex, 'w', :checked => @user_sex_woman %>
            Женский
          <% end %>
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <%= builder.label :teacher_birthday, "Дата рождения", :class => "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= builder.text_field :teacher_birthday, :value => @teacher_birthday %>
          <p class="help-block">Формат даты: дд.мм.гггг</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <%= builder.label :teacher_category, "Категория", :class => "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= builder.text_field :teacher_category, :value => @teacher_category %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <%= builder.fields_for :teacher_education do |edu_fields| %>
        <div class="control-group">
          <%= edu_fields.label :teacher_education_university, "Название ВУЗа", :class => "control-label" %>
          <div class="controls">
            <%= edu_fields.text_field :teacher_education_university, :value => @teacher_university %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <%= edu_fields.label :teacher_education_year, "Дата выпуска из ВУЗа", :class => "control-label" %>
          <div class="controls">
            <%= edu_fields.text_field :teacher_education_year, :value => @teacher_finish_univ %>
            <p class="help-block">Формат даты: дд.мм.гггг</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <%= edu_fields.label :teacher_education_graduation, "Степень", :class => "control-label" %>
          <div class="controls">
            <%= edu_fields.text_field :teacher_education_graduation, :value => @teacher_graduation %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <%= edu_fields.label :teacher_education_speciality, "Специальность", :class => "control-label" %>
          <div class="controls">
            <%= edu_fields.text_field :teacher_education_speciality, :value => @teacher_specl %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>             
        <% end %>

      <hr/>

        <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :user_login, "Логин учетной записи", :class => "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :user_login, :value => @user_login %>
              <%= link_to_function "Сгенерировать логин", "generate_login()", :class => "btn" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :password, "Пароль учетной записи", :class => "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :password, :value => @user_password  %>
                <%= link_to_function "Сгенерировать пароль", "generate_password()", :class => "btn" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Создать", :class => "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

Also, some debug information:

```
user: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  password: somepass
  teacher_attributes: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    teacher_birthday: 21.12.1990
    teacher_category: categ
    teacher_education_attributes: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
      teacher_education_graduation: grad
      teacher_education_speciality: spec
      teacher_education_university: univ
      teacher_education_year: 28.09.2000
    teacher_first_name: name
    teacher_last_name: last
    teacher_middle_name: middle
    teacher_sex: w
  user_login: schoolh_Lyp1v
utf8: ✓
controller: admins
```

My schema

```
  create_table "teacher_educations", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "teacher_id"
    t.string   "teacher_education_university"
    t.date     "teacher_education_year"
    t.string   "teacher_education_graduation"
    t.string   "teacher_education_speciality"
    t.datetime "created_at",                   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   :null => false
  end

  create_table "teacher_phones", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "teacher_id"
    t.string   "teacher_home_number"
    t.string   "teacher_mobile_number"
    t.datetime "created_at",            :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            :null => false
  end

  create_table "teachers", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "teacher_last_name"
    t.string   "teacher_first_name"
    t.string   "teacher_middle_name"
    t.date     "teacher_birthday"
    t.string   "teacher_sex"
    t.string   "teacher_category"
    t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          :null => false
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "user_login"
    t.string   "user_role"
    t.datetime "created_at",         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password"
    t.string   "salt"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are constructing your form properly to support the nested attributes then this is all you need:

```
user = User.new( params[:user] )
user.user_role = "teacher"     
if user.save
  ...
end
```

The accepts_nested_attributes mechanics will take care of the rest. If the above doesn't work then lets look at how your form is put together.

Comment: Did you update your controller action to look like my answer? Also, where are the "can't be blank" validations coming from? Your model code listing above doesn't include any. Don't apply presence check to belongs_to associations like this. Apply the presence check to the has_one association.

Comment: I updated my models (Teacher and TeacherEducation) to show validations which generating such error. Also, i have a lot of validations of name and other fields there (but i don't thonk that this is interesting)...

Comment: I removed checking id precense from belongs_to models as you suggested and now it works like a charm! Thank you!